# Can we guess the font, size, spacing , and page boarding size from a picture?

Tags: fonts, spacing, line-spacing, paper-size, size

I am really interested in the following kind of typing:

[image: here1]

[image: here2]

and I would like to type the same. The second picture is zoomed in to be more clear for the reader.

Can we guess the font, size, spacing , and page boarding and size  of the writing from the picture attached?  Plus how to get that vertical distance down the `Preface`?

Thank you all.

Thank you?

Comment: Is the file in pdf format? If so, no guesswork regarding the font is needed. Your pdf viewer should provide options from various pull-down menus to show which fonts are in use in the document.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. thats interesting i never heard of such thing. I will investigate it. What about the vertical space down `Preface`?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a ruler to measure a distance?

Comment: @Mico of course I thought about that but I thought there is a special command for it.

Comment: @Mico I check the PFD file properties, didnt give much info.

Comment: if you do have the pdf then your pdf viewer or the pdffonts  command will tell you what fonts are there and the viewer or the pdfinfo command will usually show you whether it was made by tex or other software.

Comment: @AliShadhar - How to search for the font-related information in a pdf file crucially depends on the viewer that's in use (a piece of information which you haven't disclosed so far). In Acrobat Reader, I can find out which fonts are embedded in the pdf file by clicking on File -- Properties -- Fonts.

Comment: @Mico I have acrobat reader and I managed to find the fonts but I dont know how to use them in my Latex document.  By the ways the fonts I found are so many.

Comment: @AliShadhar - How to load specific fonts in a LaTeX document is a subject that's entirely separate from how to go about finding out which fonts are embedded in a given pdf file. If you want to find out how to load various fonts, please post a new query.

Comment: Thank you @Mico I will today